# Range selector button with forward selection from the start of a time series?

Tags: plotly

I’m looking for a way to make the range selector buttons work from the start of the time series forward, instead than the default (from the end of the time series backward).
I’ve tried to look everywhere but it seems there is no way to change this behaviour.

Just to be clear, when I press the “1y” button instead of getting this

[image]

I would like to get this

[image]